# Grouping points by distance

Tags: python

What I am trying to do is group locations that all meet a minimum distance apart from one another and exclude those that don't meet that distance. Additionally, I am trying to get a group of 10.

An example, say I have 4 sets of coordinates for A, B, C, and D. I am trying to group them such that they are at least 1 mile apart from one another. The first point in the list, A, will be the starting point.
  B is 1.5 miles from A: Include in list
  C is 2 miles from B and is 2.2 miles from A: Include in list
  D is 0.5 miles from C, 0.8 miles from B, and 1.1 miles from A: Don't include
So A, B, and C would be grouped together.

I have that working, but I run into an issue where I can't get a group of 10 points because of the possibility that one point can prevent a handful of other points from meeting the criteria. How should I go forward to achieve my end goal? Thanks!

```
import csv
from geopy import distance

flag = 0
LocationIDs = []
Latitudes = []
Longitudes = []

with open('data.csv') as data:
    dataRead = csv.reader(data)
    for row in dataRead:
        LocationIDs.append(row[0])
        Latitudes.append(row[1])
        Longitudes.append(row[2])

group = [LocationIDs[0]]
groupLat = [Latitudes[0]]
groupLong = [Longitudes[0]]
LocationIDs.remove(LocationIDs[0])
Latitudes.remove(Latitudes[0])
Longitudes.remove(Longitudes[0])

for x in range(len(LocationIDs)):
    flag = 0
    for y in range(len(group)):
        currGroupLoc = (groupLat[y], groupLong[y])
        dist = distance.distance(currGroupLoc, (Latitudes[x], Longitudes[x])).miles
        print("Testing Location " + str(LocationIDs[x]) + " against " + str(group[y]))
        print(dist)
        if dist < 15:
            flag = 1

    if flag == 0 and dist < 18:
        print("Adding " + str(LocationIDs[x]))
        group.append(LocationIDs[x])
        groupLat.append(Latitudes[x])
        groupLong.append(Longitudes[x])
        LocationIDs.remove(LocationIDs[x])
        Latitudes.remove(Latitudes[x])
        Longitudes.remove(Longitudes[x])
```

Comment: Scipy.spatial.distance.cdist with "euclidean" can give you a matrix of distance between all points to all others. With the output, maybe call a output >= 1, which will give you a bool numpy matrix, with points that fulfill the condition as True and others as False. I'm not sure what you mean by the grouping, but this will be far more efficient than your double for loops.

Comment: you probably need to make a tree and do a depth-first search. you can test each new element using `pdist` from the same library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question turns out to be rather tricky. I may have mis-interpreted OP's intention, so I'll state my understanding of the task here:

> Given a set of (3D) coordinates, find all groups of points, where individual points in groups have a minimum euclidean separation distance between them.

I'm not sure if OP wants the biggest group (which is somewhat easier), or all groups, but for future reference I'll solve for the all-groups case.

First, we find, for each point, the indices of the other points for which the minimum distance criterion is satisfied:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

coords = [[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5],[5,4,3],[3,4,5]]
boolean = cdist(coords, coords) > 2
matrix = [[] for __ in range(len(boolean))]
for row_i, row in enumerate(boolean):
    matrix[row_i] = list([i for i, is_true in enumerate(row) if is_true])
print(matrix)    # [[2, 3, 4], [3], [0, 3], [0, 1, 2, 4], [0, 3]]
```

Next (and here's the tricky bit), we find all possible groups that fulfill the criteria:

```
from copy import deepcopy

def _remove_from_rows(element, m):
    for key, values in m.items():
        m[key] = list([val for val in values if val != element])
    return m

def _remove_rows_without(value, m):
    m_ = m.copy()
    for key, values in m_.items():
        if value not in values:
            del m[key]
    return m

def _remove_smaller_keys(value, m):
    keys = sorted(m.keys())
    for key in keys:
        if key < value:
            del m[key]
        else:
            break
    return m

def recursive(m, group, clusters):
    key = group[-1]
    m_ = deepcopy(m)

    values = m_.pop(key)
    m_ = _remove_rows_without(key, m_)
    m_ = _remove_from_rows(key, m_)
    m_ = _remove_smaller_keys(key, m_)

    if not m_:
        return group
    for value in values:
        if value not in m_ or value < key:
            continue
        group_ = group + [value]
        clusters.append(recursive(m_, group_, clusters))
    return []

def start(m):
    groups = []
    for i in range(len(m)):
        group = [i]
        output = recursive(m, group, groups)
        del m[i]
        if output:
            groups.append(output)
    unique_groups = [val for val in groups if not
                 any(set(val) < set(i) for i in groups)]
    return unique_groups

matrix_ = [[1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 9],
          [0, 2, 5, 6, 8, 9],
          [0, 1, 3, 5, 6, 8],
          [2, 4, 6, 7, 8],
          [0, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9],
          [0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 7],
          [1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8],
          [0, 3, 5, 6, 9],
          [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 9],
          [0, 1, 4, 7, 8]]

matrix = dict()
for i, values in enumerate(matrix_):
    matrix[i] = values

print(start(matrix))
# [[0, 1, 2, 5], [0, 1, 9], [0, 4, 5], [0, 4, 9], [0, 5, 7], [0, 7, 9], 
#  [1, 2, 6, 8], [1, 8, 9], [2, 3, 6, 8], [3, 4, 6, 8], [3, 6, 7], [4, 8, 9]]
```

I've used a larger synthetic matrix dataset to provide adequate testing, with results manually verified. Now for the details.

The matrix represents, for each point (per row), the indices of the other points that have at least the minimum distance between them. There is therefore symmetry, in that if point 2 (`matrix[2]`) has a value of 7, point 7 (`matrix[7]`) must have a value of 2. I'm using zero-based indexing for points here (point 0 exist) for clarity.

I find it easier to understand the implementation of the code by first working out the algorithm on paper. Taking into account the aforementioned symmetry, I approached the grouping task by this way:

For each row_i, row in matrix.items():

`[0] => [1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 9]`

Get all other rows that have row_i as a value, and drop row_i from each of the rows:

```
1: [2, 5, 6, 8, 9]
2: [1, 3, 5, 6, 8]
4: [3, 5, 6, 8, 9]
5: [1, 2, 4, 6, 7]
7: [3, 5, 6, 9]
9: [1, 4, 7, 8]
```

The current group is now `[0]`.

Next, add the indices on the row_i row, to group, individually, if the row corresponding to the indice exist in the matrix subset. We see that for 1, it exists in the 0th row, and is represented in the matrix subset below. Therefore, we form the group `[0, 1]`, which now has as its row the indices in the 1th row, but with all values smaller than the row indice (1) dropped. This is irrelevant for our 1th row because the separation between 0 and 1 is, well, 1, but it is necessary for later steps.

```
[0, 1] => [2, 5, 6, 8, 9]
2: [3, 5, 6, 8]
5: [2, 4, 6, 7]
9: [4, 7, 8]
```

As can be seen, we drop the 4th and 7th rows because they do not have 1 in their rows. This representation is because, if we assign a group with the 0th and the 1st point, because the 4th and 7th points are closer than the minimum distance to the 1st point, the 4th and 7th points cannot participate in this specific group.

We repeat the procedure, noting that for row_i row (`[0, 1] => [2, 5, 6, 8, 9]`), only indices whose corresponding row is represented in the matrix subset below, should be added to the group.

For demonstration I'll complete the process.

```
[0, 1, 2] => [3, 5, 6, 8]
5: [4, 6, 7]

[0, 1, 2, 5] => [6, 7]
```

Because the matrix subset is now exhausted, we have completed the group, `[0, 1, 2, 5]`. The group is complete when the matrix subset is exhausted, or when none of the indices in the row_i row has a corresponding representation in the matrix_subset, or when row_i row is empty. Which all corresponds to the same physical situation, that of having no more points that can maintain the minimum distance to all existing points in the group. Remember that we have to repeat the procedure for all values along row_i row, meaning we need to do `[0, 2]`, `[0, 4]`, ... . You should find, however, that the search space decreases at-least quadratically as you go down the rows, mainly because of the step where we discard all points in rows in matrix subset, that are smaller than row_i (due to symmetry as described above).

Once the algorithm is well understood, the code implementation is rather straightforward (but still quite a pain to get it right). I'm not sure which parts require some explanation, so just write in the comments if there are any areas you feel lost in. Do try to work out the algorithm first though.

I believe the implementation is right, although it is definitely not designed for efficiency, do comment if you spot any errors, thanks!

Thoughts: I have a strong feeling that somewhere in some obscure (or maybe not) library, this entire chunk can be replaced by a one-liner. Oh wells.